# Click a button that is not a link and doesn't have an id

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm a noob in using selenium, I've searched google before asking here but none of the things I've found before worked for me. I'm just looking for a way to click a button that doesn't have an ID or a link.

The button I'm trying to click is as following :

```
<a class="nav-link block pointer" data-vce="btn-popup" data-popup="login" data-popup-close-by-overlay="1" data-popup-source="Top Nav" data-event-category="Sign In Popup" data-event-label="top_nav" data-tea-event="sign_in_popup" data-tea-source="Top Nav"> Se connecter </a>
```

```
links = driver.find_elements("xpath", "//a[@href]")
for link in links:
    print(link.get_attribute("innerHTML"))
    if " Se connecter " in link.get_attribute("innerHTML"):
        link.click()
        break
```

I've tried this but didnt work as the button doesnt have an innerHTML

and i've tried this :

```
class_connecter = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'nav-link block pointer')
button_connecter = class_connecter[0]
button_connecter.click()
```

but didnt work too : no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".nav-link block pointer"}

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//a[text()=" Se connecter "]'))).click()
```

Imports statement you would need:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

Comment: thank you for your help ! why do you wait though ?

Comment: At times it may take some time for webpage to load completely and for the desired web element to be visible/clickable. In such instances, although your locator strategy is correct, selenium may throw `Unable to locate element:` exception, as it may have tried to locate element before even the web page could load. In these cases, waits help.

Comment: oh i see, and another question, here you use //a, but would i need to use //button if what i wanted to click is a button ?

Comment: Here `a` is the tagname of the desired element. If the desired element you wish for has a tagname `<button>` then yes you should use `//button`.

Comment: I can't upvote your comment as my account is freshly created :(
Sorry Shawn but thank you

Answer (score 0):

there are several approaches to getting this work. To find the best one, some questions I always ask myself are the followings:

- Which attributes may not change over time?
- Which attributes describe better the element I want to get?
- The inner HTML is gonna be always the same?

I like to use XPath for this stuff because it is more flexible and allows you to add many attributes of the HTML as you want. And some logic with them too.
Here is an example considering the button text and the class of the button

```py
button_xpath = '//a[contains(text(), "Se connecter") and @class="nav-link block pointer"]'
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath(button_xpath)
if button:
    button.click()
else:
    print('button not found')
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thank you so much for the informations ! It worked :)
In my case the attributes you used are not gonna change overtime so it's good.